# Understanding the derivation of the partial trace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, tensor-calculus, trace

Consider the following derivation:

$$
\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}_{B}}(\hat{O})=\sum_{K}\langle\tilde{B}_{K}|\hat{O}| \tilde{B}_{K}\rangle=\sum_{K} \sum_{i} \sum_{I} \sum_{j} \sum_{J}\langle i, I|\hat{O}| j, J\rangle|B_{i}\rangle\langle B_{j}| \otimes\langle\tilde{B}_{K} \mid \tilde{B}_{I}\rangle\langle\tilde{B}_{J} \mid \tilde{B}_{K}\rangle \\
=\sum_{i} \sum_{j}(\sum_{K}\langle i, K|\hat{O}| j, K\rangle)|B_{i}\rangle\langle B_{j}|
$$
using the orthonormality of the basis elements. We see that the partial trace defines now an operator that lives only inside $\hat{H}_{A}$ whose matrix elements are
$$
\langle i |\hat{O}_{A}^{\text {reduced }}| j\rangle= (\sum_{K}\langle i, K|\hat{O}| j, K\rangle)
$$
for $\hat{O}_{A}^{\text {reduced }}=\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}_{B}}(\hat{O})$.

If we now perform a second trace over the Hilbert space of $\hat{H}_{A}$ we get
$$
\operatorname{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}_{A}}(\hat{O}_{A}^{\text {reduced }})=\sum_{i} \sum_{K}\langle i, K|\hat{O}| i, K\rangle=\operatorname{Tr}(\hat{O}) \,.
$$
In other words we have the important relation
$$
\mathrm{Tr}=\mathrm{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}_{A}} \mathrm{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}_{B}}
$$
i.e. performing all the partial traces is equivalent to performing the full trace. Note the order would not matter.

Note that the capital letters are in the Hilbert space B whilst the lower-case letters are in Hilbert space A.

I am unsure about the first line of mathematics and would greatly appreciate if someone can clarify for me, perhaps by explaining to me in more detail as to what is happening here.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Also, can you be a bit more specific about what's unclear to you here?

Comment: In the first line of maths I'm not sure exactly where the 5 summations came from. I'm new to this type of maths so what is probably quite obvious for most people is not so so easy for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The math seems clear to me, but you need to be careful with notation, especially in the first line. Apparently you used $\vert i,I \rangle \equiv \vert B_{i}, B_{I} \rangle$. The only line that needs some explanation is the first one. Consider $$ \sum_K \langle K \vert\hat O \vert K \rangle $$ and multiply on the left and on the right of $\hat O$ for the identity matrix $\sum_{i,j}  \vert i, I \rangle \langle i, I \vert $, you get:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i,I} \sum_{j,J} \sum_{K} \langle K \vert i,I \rangle \langle i, I \vert \hat O \vert j, J \rangle \langle j,J \vert K \rangle.
\end{equation}
You can manipulate the terms $\langle K \vert i, I \rangle$ because this is a number. The expression above becomes:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i,I} \sum_{j,J} \sum_{K}  \langle i, I \vert \hat O \vert j, J \rangle \vert j \rangle \langle i \vert \langle J \vert K \rangle \langle K \vert I \rangle.
\end{equation}
Considering an orthonormal basis, $\langle J \vert K \rangle \langle K \vert I \rangle = \delta_{I,K} \delta_{J,K}$. This leads you to the expression:
\begin{equation}
\langle j \vert \hat{O}^{reduced}_{A} \vert i \rangle = \sum_{K} \langle j, K \vert \hat O \vert i,K \rangle.
\end{equation}
And that's it.